# how to declare that you have full superuser permissions when prompted on terminal?

Tags: root

I am a very basic Ubuntu user. Everytime I am trying the terminal, I receive the following question and I do not know how to answer: Do you have full superuser (root) permissions? I want to configure the TV at home to send video via HDMI port. When I write "get-edid", the question appears. y, yes or -y do not work. I am the root and know the password.

I would like to learn how to say "yes" on Ubuntu?

Thank you in advance.

Miraç

Comment: Please edit your question and explain what you do when this happens and the message itself.

Comment: Thanks but the only information I can give is this much. What is nouveau driver? Or are you just speaking French?

Comment: But I have a **RADEON HD 4200**.

Comment: You should try `sudo get-edid`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho already on it and yes it does need sudo (took a bit of time installing it ;))

Comment: :) thank you.  Now I am able to see the _EDID_ information. But still wonder how to say yes.

Comment: It is a question you can not answer when it shows: it is a comment echo'd to your screen as a hint to the problem it sees: get-edid can not access a command. The answer to the question is `no` and the action to get rid of the question is to use `sudo` in front of the command (the program then sees that the answer is yes and continues ;) )

Comment: How can I close the question? Do I add [DONE] to the subject line?

Comment: No need. Accepting the question will make it disappear from the frontpage. The website will once every so often put questions with no answer back to the frontpage (and will ignore accepted ones)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `sudo` in front of the command `get-edid`. You are accessing hardware so it will need to issue commands that a normal user can not use.

This

```
get-edid | parse-edid
```

will give ...

```
mmap /dev/zero: Operation not permitted
get-edid: error initialising realmode interface
get-edid: do you have full superuser (root) permissions?
```

because the `mmap /dev/zero` needs root permissions.

```
sudo get-edid | parse-edid
```

will show something similar to...

```
Performing real mode VBE call
Interrupt 0x10 ax=0x4f00 bx=0x0 cx=0x0
Function supported
Call successful
```

etc.

Comment: no problem! Glad to be able to help @MiraçGül :)